# Summing up a field in solr

Tags: solr, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a Solr index with fields :

```
STR(k_id)
STR(k_pid)
INT(k_count) >= 1
```

I want a query which achieves this :

```
SELECT k_pid, SUM(k_count) FROM index GROUP BY k_pid
```

How can I do the sum operation on the k_count field? Appreciate any help.

```
http://<myhost>:<port>/solr/collection2/select?q=*:*&debugQuery=true&fl=mk_pid,mk_id,mk_count&group=true&group.field=mk_pid
```

Comment: have a look at this :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966051/apache-solr-sum-of-data-resulted-from-group-by

Answer (score 4):

You can't execute sum operations with the field collapsing (group) feature.
Use the stats component for this purpose : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent